# rightrotate without bitwise operators

Tags: language-agnostic, graphics, bit-manipulation, hlsl, math

How can I implement the rightrotate (and leftrotate) operations on 32 bit integers without using any bitwise operations?

I need this because High Level Shader Language (HLSL) does not allow bitwise oeprations upon numbers, and I need rightrotate for a specific shader I'm trying to implement.

Comment: Standard arithmetic operations, integers, unsigned integers, arrays. All the basics except bitwise operations really

Comment: Could you please give an example? just one bit?

Comment: The best example would be wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Rotate_no_carry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For unsigned integers, divide by 2 and add 2^32 if the number was odd, for right rotate. For left, multiply by two and add 1 if it was above 2^32 - 1.

Comment: Note: depending on language, you might have to handle overflow and rounding. E.g. for left, you might have to subtract 2^32 before multiplying by 2.

Comment: If you don't need the carry bit to wrap around then you can simply divide and multiply by 2 for right and left rotate.

Comment: @slebetman: that would then by definition be a shift rather than a rotate, surely?

Comment: How about for signed integers?

Comment: For signed integers, I'd just cast them to unsigned, do the rotate, and cast back :) But that's a bit language specific (not to mention lazy).

Comment: I can't do that kind of cast in HLSL as far as I know, otherwise that would be fine. The only casts in HLSL are the kind which will slice off some of the range.

Comment: It might depend a little on how you rotate. The easy way might be to multiply negative numbers by -1, rotate as above, then mutliply by -1 again...but, if you want to keep the sign, you would rotate on 31 bits (so replace 2^32 with 2^31 in the formula above - bit 32 will always be 0 for positive numbers).

Comment: I'm not sure, what kind of rightroate do I need for SHA256 and that'll tell you what type I need ;)

Comment: From what I can tell [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), they're unsigned.

Comment: Ok, I'll go with unsigned for now, and see if I get correct results :)